# Graphing in R/looping through matrices

Tags: r, loops, matrix, graph

I'm writing a program that basically allows a user to retrieve weather data for whatever zipcode they specify. User inputs a zipcode, a bunch of code runs that does a lot of substring and gsub on a weather website's source code to finally spit out the current temperature. My program prints out the temperature for the specified zipcode and the next 10 sequential zipcodes. I'm trying to plot this information in a graph and am so far having trouble figuring out how to do it. There is an exercise module provided to me that shows me how to graph a matrix so I'm trying to store all the relevant information in a matrix and take it from there but am having trouble doing that.

```
Input = "20904" # User provides an input for this
ZipData<- as.numeric(ZipData$zip) # Creates a list of zipcodes from a csv file
match(Input,ZipData) 
index <- match(Input,ZipData) # Stores the index at which the Input appears in the list 
index
n = index + 10 # The next 10 zipcodes
n
for (i in index:n){
Input <- toString(ZipData[i])

# A bunch of code that retrieves the cityName and temperature and prints it out as a string

cityName <- # Some substring function
temperature <- # Some substring function
a <- paste("The current temperature for",cityName, Input, "is", temperature, sep=" ")
print(a)
# Now I'm trying to create a matrix with 10 rows and 2 columns with the first column containing the 10 zipcodes and the second column containing their respective temperatures.
ZipGraph <- matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=2)
for(j in 1:nrow){
  ZipGraph[j,]<- c(Input,temperature)
}


}


     # Should be printing out                          
       [,1]    [,2]                            
 [1,] "20904" "79.8"
 [2,] "20905" "77.0"
 [3,] "20906" "76.9"
 [4,] "20907" "80.0"
 [5,] "20908" "81.5"
 [6,] "20909" "82.2"
 [7,] "20910" "81.4"
 [8,] "20911" "82.0"
 [9,] "20913" "83.2"
[10,] "20915" "85.5"

   # Prints out

       [,1]    [,2]  
 [1,] "20915" "85.5"
 [2,] "20915" "85.5"
 [3,] "20915" "85.5"
 [4,] "20915" "85.5"
 [5,] "20915" "85.5"
 [6,] "20915" "85.5"
 [7,] "20915" "85.5"
 [8,] "20915" "85.5"
 [9,] "20915" "85.5"
[10,] "20915" "85.5"
```

Now for some reason the last for loop is only reading the final ZipData [i] value and isn't iterating through and reading it in to ZipGraph as I hoped it would. How can I fix this?

Next step is to graph this matrix and I have no idea how to do that. Help appreciated.

Comment: `nrow` is undefined. `temperature` is undefined. You probably only need one loop, something along these lines: `for(j in 1:10) {ZipGraph[j,] <- c(ZipData[i+index-1], temperature)}` Replace temperature with code that returns the temperature while taking in presumably `ZipData[i+index-1]`

Comment: @Vlo I did define nrow and I intentionally left temperature undefined as my comment implies it stores a string value obtained after running other code that I didn't feel was relevant to post. I will try your solution.

Comment: What kind of graph are you looking for when you graph the matrix? Topographical, with temperatures assigned to their zip codes on a map? Dot/scatter? Bar?

Comment: Also, what Vlo said about one loop is correct. Your second loop is iterating over your entire matrix for each step of the first loop, which means every value in the matrix is entirely replaced by the result on the ith step, terminating on the 10th step of the outer loop.

Comment: @plagueheart A bar graph is just fine. With the zipcode on the x axis and the temperature on the y. As for the looping error, can you propose a solution? I tried this : defined j = 1 before the beginning of the first for loop then replaced the second for loop with:

`ZipGraph[j,]<- c(Input,temperature)`
`j = j+1`

But this doesn't work either. I'm stumped.

Comment: I suspect the problem (I am an R neophyte myself) is that you can't do an accumulator like that in a for loop in R. What you may need to do is define i differently--rather than having it run from index:n, let it run from 1 to 10, and pull the zipcodes from ZipData via something like ZipData[index+(i-1)]. Since they're not contiguous, you may need to play around with this. I'll give it a shot myself later today when I have time, and also see what I can do with your graph. ETA: Which is exactly what Vlo suggested, actually. Haha.

Comment: @plagueheart Vlo was actually helping me with a slightly different problem. I had to update my question to capture the repeating of the final value as I did not anticipate encountering this problem before. I understand why a second for-loop wouldn't work but I don't see what's wrong with the solution I propose above. Please let me know if you discover a solution. Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're seeing when you say it "doesn't work"? If you defined j outside the loop, it should work once, and then on the next round, it'll throw "subscript out of bound" errors, as j will be 11 at the completion of your loop the first time.

Comment: @plagueheart I finally fixed it after some heavy debugging. Turns out, creating the matrix within the for-loop was what was throwing the code off. On every iteration it created a new matrix and filled it in with the current i value. Simple fix. Just create and define the matrix before the for-loop and then fill it in within the loop.

Comment: Yes, that would do it. Variable definition absolutely has to happen outside of the loop or that sort of thing will happen. If you've got the code sorted out, you may want to answer your own question and mark it closed!